# How do I get GeoLabels to show up on map

Tags: bugs, warning-messages, geography, geographics

**Bug introduced in 11.0**

---

This code draws the map, but does not show the labels.

```
    GeoListPlot[{Entity["Country", "Algeria"], Entity["Country", "Egypt"],
      Entity["Country", "Morocco"], Entity["Country", "Madagascar"], 
      Entity["Country", "Tunisia"], Entity["Country", "Reunion"], 
      Entity["Country", "SouthAfrica"], Entity["Country", "Ethiopia"], 
      Entity["Country", "Zimbabwe"]}, GeoLabels -> True]
```

The error reported is:

*Table is not a Graphics primitive or directive.*

[image: Plot generated by code]

Comment: It works in `10.4.1.0`. What version are you in?

Answer (score 11):

I confirm the problem occurs with V11.0.1 running OS X. It looks a bug to me. Here is a work-around.

```
GeoListPlot[
  {Entity["Country", "Algeria"], Entity["Country", "Egypt"], 
   Entity["Country", "Morocco"], Entity["Country", "Madagascar"], 
   Entity["Country", "Tunisia"], Entity["Country", "Reunion"], 
   Entity["Country", "SouthAfrica"], Entity["Country", "Ethiopia"], 
   Entity["Country", "Zimbabwe"]}, 
  GeoLabels -> (Text[#2[[2]], Reverse[#3[[1]]]] &)]
```

[image: map]

#### Edit

It occurred to me, after sleeping on it, that some viewers of this answer might be interested in how I worked out a work-around, so I present a description of the process.

The documentation article[`GeoLabels`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoLabels.html) says that the option wants a function with three arguments, which are

1. A graphic representing of the geographic object (Polygon) or its location (Point).
2. the region entity itself
3. the region entity's position on the map (latitude, longitude)

The article also shows an example of such a function where the label appears as a tooltip. I adapted that to a reduced version of the problem as a tool to examine the arguments as shown below.

```
GeoListPlot[
  {Entity["Country", "Madagascar"], Entity["Country", "Reunion"],
   Entity["Country", "SouthAfrica"], Entity["Country", "Zimbabwe"]},
  GeoLabels -> (Tooltip[#1, {#1, #2, #3}] &)]
```

[image: tooltip]

Because the 2nd argument is the region entity and the 2nd argument of that is the region's name, I use `#2[[2]]` to extract the name. Also, because the the position is given as {latitude, longitude} but plotted as {longitude, latitude}, I reverse the position extracted from the 3rd argument. I also add 0.75 degrees of latitude so that Reunion is not hidden by its label.

```
GeoListPlot[
  {Entity["Country", "Madagascar"], Entity["Country", "Reunion"],
   Entity["Country", "SouthAfrica"], Entity["Country", "Zimbabwe"]},
  GeoLabels -> (Text[#2[[2]], Reverse[#3[[1]]] + {0, .75}] &)]
```

This produces the desired labeling.

[image: labeled_map]

#### Update

I reported the OP's problem to Wolfram tech support. I have received an answer confirming it is a bug in V11. I quote the relevant part of the reply.

> Your observation is correct. The simple expression [GeoLabels -> True] should work. The issue has been reported to our developers and it will hopefully be fixed in the future release of Mathematica.

Comment: Bug on V11.0.1 running Window 10 too.

Comment: The bug seems to be fixed since v11.1.0. However i find the labels to be more readable (better positioned) with your method ;)